# R: problems plotting p-values from conover test (Dunn's works fine)

Tags: r, ggpubr, rstatix

I am having some trouble with an error message I can't solve.

I use the following code in to run a Kruskal Wallis in R and then do a pairwise comparison using Dunn's:

```
res.kruskal <- mydata %>% kruskal_test(values ~ group)
res.kruskal
stat.test <- mydata %>% dunn_test(values ~ group, p.adjust.method = "hochberg") 
stat.test
stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "group")
```

I then use this result to plot out the significances like so:

```
ggboxplot(mydata, x = "group", y = "values, fill = "group") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, hide.ns = FALSE)
```

And get is nice looking plot (hooray!)

[image]

But the Cover Test is apparently more powerful and preferred over Dunn's... (any opinions on this would be welcome too!). Running the following code returns an error:

```
res.kruskal <- immdatamed %>% kruskal_test(LplastinTL ~ group)
res.kruskal
attach(immdatamed)
stat.test <- conover.test(LplastinTL, group, method = "hochberg") 
stat.test
stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "group")
detach(immdatamed)

stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "group")
Error in asserttat_group_columns_exists(test) : 
  data should contain group1 and group2 columns
```

I can't figure this out... I can run the Conover test fine but can't solve the above error to get it to work with ggboxplot.

I would actually prefer to use the more aesthetically pleasing ggplot & geom_boxplot but can't get that to interface with Dunn_test at all...

Any solutions would be most welcome!

Thank you

P.S. I was using this with ggplot: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots but I cont want a wilcoxon or t.test for pairwise comparison...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very long to explain what I am doing since I expect you are inexperienced with both R and the stats.  I won't even cover why Conover vs Dunn thats more a [stats exchange thing see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141856/what-is-the-difference-between-various-kruskal-wallis-post-hoc-tests)

**Please** in the future be clear about what packages you are using, you never mention `rstatix` for example.  ***Please*** include a sample of your data.

```r
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922336/r-problems-plotting-p-values-from-conover-test-dunns-works-fine
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)

# I'm going to get the Conover test from this package 

require(DescTools)

# You didn't provide data I will use mtcars

mydata <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, gear)
mydata$gear <- factor(mydata$gear)

# Here's what you were doing

stat.test.dunn <- mydata %>% dunn_test(mpg ~ gear, p.adjust.method = "hochberg") 
stat.test.dunn <- stat.test.dunn %>% add_xy_position(x = "gear")
stat.test.dunn
#> # A tibble: 3 x 13
#>   .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p   p.adj p.adj.signif
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 mpg   3      4         15    12      3.76 1.69e-4 5.06e-4 ***         
#> 2 mpg   3      5         15     5      1.65 9.98e-2 2.00e-1 ns          
#> 3 mpg   4      5         12     5     -1.14 2.54e-1 2.54e-1 ns          
#> # … with 4 more variables: y.position <dbl>, groups <named list>, xmin <int>,
#> #   xmax <int>

ggboxplot(mydata, x = "gear", y = "mpg", fill = "gear") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test.dunn, hide.ns = FALSE)
```

[image]

Here's how we can "fake it out"

```r
stat.test.Conover <- DescTools::ConoverTest(mpg ~ gear, mydata, method = "hochberg" ) 
stat.test.Conover
#> 
#>  Conover's test of multiple comparisons : hochberg  
#> 
#>     mean.rank.diff    pval    
#> 4-3      13.658333 8.5e-05 ***
#> 5-3       7.966667  0.0767 .  
#> 5-4      -5.691667  0.1434    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
stat.test.Conover[[1]]
#>     mean rank diff         pval
#> 4-3      13.658333 8.490683e-05
#> 5-3       7.966667 7.666748e-02
#> 5-4      -5.691667 1.433731e-01

things_we_want <- rstatix::add_significance(data = as.data.frame(stat.test.Conover[[1]]))
things_we_want
#>   mean rank diff         pval pval.signif
#> 1      13.658333 8.490683e-05        ****
#> 2       7.966667 7.666748e-02          ns
#> 3      -5.691667 1.433731e-01          ns

stat.test.Conover <- stat.test.dunn
stat.test.Conover
#> # A tibble: 3 x 13
#>   .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p   p.adj p.adj.signif
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 mpg   3      4         15    12      3.76 1.69e-4 5.06e-4 ***         
#> 2 mpg   3      5         15     5      1.65 9.98e-2 2.00e-1 ns          
#> 3 mpg   4      5         12     5     -1.14 2.54e-1 2.54e-1 ns          
#> # … with 4 more variables: y.position <dbl>, groups <named list>, xmin <int>,
#> #   xmax <int>
stat.test.Conover$p.adj <- things_we_want$pval
stat.test.Conover$p.adj.signif <- things_we_want$pval.signif
stat.test.Conover
#> # A tibble: 3 x 13
#>   .y.   group1 group2    n1    n2 statistic       p   p.adj p.adj.signif
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>       
#> 1 mpg   3      4         15    12      3.76 1.69e-4 8.49e-5 ****        
#> 2 mpg   3      5         15     5      1.65 9.98e-2 7.67e-2 ns          
#> 3 mpg   4      5         12     5     -1.14 2.54e-1 1.43e-1 ns          
#> # … with 4 more variables: y.position <dbl>, groups <named list>, xmin <int>,
#> #   xmax <int>

ggboxplot(mydata, x = "gear", y = "mpg", fill = "gear") +
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test.Conover, hide.ns = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Chuck P, that worked! My apologies for not stating the package and not providing sample data. I will do so in the future. Thank you very much! You have saved me hours of my time manually annotating plots.

Comment: More than welcome and we ask for more info mainly so we can help.

Comment: Hello Chuck, I am having trouble again with this same issue. I don't know where the problem lies. I had copied and pasted your code and used it successfully but in my new project it isn't working. Do you think there would be a problem in switching from ggboxplot to ggdotplot? The code keeps giving the actual p-values, not the "*" designations lifted from the dunn.test. Is there a way we can communicate, sharing my current code, without starting a new question for this old question? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Tyrone no guarantee when I can look at it,  there is nothing about the code above that relies on box versus dot plots it works for both.  I'd post another question and make sure you give us enough of your actual data and code that someone could help.

Comment: Thanks Chuck. Managed to fix the issue: the Conover test doesn't like lines with NA in it. Thanks

Comment: Okay that's the problem with letting us guess what the data is